# Spring JPA - How to return distinct results based on multiple columns

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table that looks kinda like this

| Entity Name | Year | Person Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| School 1 | 2021 | Person 1 |
| School 1 | 2021 | Person 2 |
| School 1 | 2020 | Person 1 |
| School 2 | 2021 | Person 1 |

I want to be able to use Spring JPA to return only one result per Entity Name.
For example, the results would be School 1, School 2. I don't care which School 1 row is retrieved, I just need to only retrieve one.
I need to be able to use a Specification, return Pagination results, and sort the results.

Here is what I have tried so far

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Model, UUID>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<Model>{
}
```

Service

```
repository.findAll(Specification
                .searchByDtoSpec(searchDto), page)
                .map(this::mapToDto);
```

Specification

```
    public static Specification<Model> searchByDtoSpec(
            final SearchDto searchDto) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            query.multiselect(root.get("entityName"),root.get("personName")).distinct(true);

            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
        };
    }
```

Comment: As far as i know  distinct with multiselect is not supported in Criteria API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, I was not able to find a way without using CriteriaBuilder and CriteriaQuery. I had to combine a CriteriaQuery multiselect and a CriteriaQuery distinct
Here is a snippet of my code to help anyone else in my situation:

```
public Page<Model> findAllByFilters(final Pageable page,
            final SearchDto searchDto) {
        final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

        final CriteriaQuery<Model> cq = cb.createQuery(Model.class);

        final Root<Model> root = cq.from(Model.class);

        final List<Predicate> predicates = getCustomPredicates(root, cq, cb, searchDto, 
            currentDate, false);
        cq.where(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
        cq.multiselect(root.get("entityName"), root.get("year"), root.get("personName");
        cq.distinct(true);

        final TypedQuery<Model> tq = em.createQuery(cq);

        // Code for Pagination
        ...

        final List<Model> list = tq.getResultList();
        return new PageImpl<Model>(list, page, count);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `Repository` interface add a method like this

```
Model findFirstByOrderByPersonNameAsc();
```

You can order it however you want. You can also return an optional `Optional<Model>` if you would like.

Comment: I updated my question. I need to be able to use Specification and Pagination. Also, won't findFirst only return one result? I need one result for each Entity Name

Comment: Ah, ok.  I must have misread your question. Is `query.groupBy(column_name);` not working for you?